# UseEffect hook executes multiple times on updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am updating state of parent component from child component's useEffect hook. Follwing is the piece of code from child component. Here useEffect is getting called twice. Not sure how can I avoid it.

```js
useEffect = () => { const flag = someApi; setStateOfParent(flag),[]}
```

Comment: can you post maybe a codesandbox link or code for both parent and child components?

Answer (score 10):

This below code will fix the issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // executed only once
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely avoid setting state inside `useEffect` because it will trigger a new render. Also, if you specify your effect dependencies you will have better control over it and assure that it will only get executed when one of those dependencies change.

Answer (score -4):

You do not set state in useEffect. Make a function to get data from API, call it in useEffect and setState in that function. You can check a an example code below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getImage();
}, []); // Calling getImage function to fetch data

const [items, set] = useState([]);

async function getImage() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://picsum.photos/v2/list");
    let image = response.data;

    for (var i in image) {
      let x = "https://picsum.photos/id/";
      let y = image[i].id;
      let v = image[i].width;
      image[i].author = `${x}${y}/${v}/${image[i].height}`;
      image[i].height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 650) + 300;
      let z = image[i].height;

      image[i].download_url = `url(${x}${y}/${v}/${z})`;
    }
    set(image); // setting state after fetching data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried calling my function from useEffect as you have mentioned still it gets called multiple times. So if I comment the code which updates state of parent component useEffect is called only once.